# User still Anonymous after successful login Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

So I have created a traditional login form. After a successful login, it redirects to my dashboard then redirect backs to login. After checking, the User is Anonymous and is authenticated. I was also able to dump the user on my custom provider. I suspect, Symfony doesn't save it on session. Why is that so?

Here's what I've done so far:

security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        user_provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: security_login
                check_path: security_login
                default_target_path: dashboard

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:
            - ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
            - ROLE_ADMIN
```

framework.yml

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #default_locale: en
    #csrf_protection: ~
    #http_method_override: true

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'

    #esi: ~
    #fragments: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

    cache:
        # Put the unique name of your app here: the prefix seed
        # is used to compute stable namespaces for cache keys.
        #prefix_seed: your_vendor_name/app_name

        # The app cache caches to the filesystem by default.
        # Other options include:

        # Redis
        #app: cache.adapter.redis
        #default_redis_provider: redis://localhost

        # APCu (not recommended with heavy random-write workloads as memory fragmentation can cause perf issues)
        #app: cache.adapter.apcu
```

Userprovider

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {   
        $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->loadByUsername($username);

        if ($user) {
            return $user;
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return User::class === $class;
    }
}
```

User

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("email", message="Email is already taken.")
 * @UniqueEntity("username", message="Username is already taken.")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Username must not be blank.")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Password must not be blank.")
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Email must not be blank.")
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="First name must not be blank.")
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Last name must not be blank.")
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array")
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = [];
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): User
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): User
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword) : User
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword() : ?string
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): User
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    // Overriden Methods

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {

    }

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof WebserviceUser) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->salt !== $user->getSalt()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->username !== $user->getUsername()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->roles,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->roles
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Note: Im using docker with Nginx and PHP-FPM images.

Comment: This is embarassing, but the problem is in equalTo() of User. I have no WebserviceUser class.

Comment: can you explain in an answer please i've the same problem

Comment: @Hooli basically Symfony checks for equalTo() whether the session has been changed. Since i dont have WebUserService class equalTo() always returns false that why symfony is logging me out.

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced the same issue myself today and had a similar facepalm moment. In my case it turned out that we were not serializing all of the required User entity data to be used within the `AdvancedUserInterface` methods.

For example:

`UserEntity`:

```
...

public function isEnabled ()
{
    return (0 < $this->status);
}

public function serialize ()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // $this->status, <- this was missing and needed added
    ));
}

public function unserialize ($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password
        //, $this->status <-- this was missing and needed added

    ) = unserialize($serialized, array ("allowed_classes" => false));
}

...
```

Because we were not serializing the object with its `$this->status` property, the `isEnabled()` method was failing when working with an un-serialized `UserEntity`. Once we added the property and cleared the session it was working again.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone, i just spent a few hours on this and i had a similar issue.. make sure the user serialization is correct

Cause of much pain..

```
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id, $this->username, $this->password, // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list ($this->id, $this->username, $this->password, // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized, array('allowed_classes' => false));
}
```

FIXED

```
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id, $this->username, $this->password, $this->salt,
    ));
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list ($this->id, $this->username, $this->password, $this->salt) 

        = unserialize($serialized, array('allowed_classes' => false));
}
```

User creation ...

```
        $user->setSalt(bin2hex(random_bytes(16)));

        $encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha512', true, 5000);

        $encodedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());

        $user->setPassword($encodedPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced with this problem during project migration from Symfony2 to Symfony 5. So, what I did:

Renamed User entity file to User.php_

Ran php bin/console make:user as described [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-create-your-user-class)

Then compared methods from a generated entity with the existing entity.

Also, removed \Serializable interface from the User entity as I didn't need it (if you need an entity to be serializable, just implement it properly)

If you're migrating from older versions of Symfony to 4/5 version, it's better to re-generate form login with all related stuff (like config, login and registration controller) and re-implement it: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html